# Studying continuity of $f(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{x-y}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let

$$f(x,y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{x+y}{x-y} & , x \neq y \\
      1 & , x=y \\
\end{array} 
\right.$$

I want to see whether $f(x,y)$ is continuous at points $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2:x=y\}$. In understand I have to compute a limit, but I am not sure how to do it (not sure about notation either). I see that we need $x \to y$ somehow, but these are both variables here. How to deal with this? Is something like

\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y) \to (x,x)} \frac{x+y}{x-y}
\end{equation}

correct? Does this restrict *how we approach the function* in any way? What about defining $x=y+\varepsilon$ and then studying $\varepsilon \to 0$?

Answer (score 4):

We will prove it isn't continuous at (0,0), in particular, the limit $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y),$$ does not exist.  If the limit did exist, then any way $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ should give the same limit.  But this is not so:

$$\lim_{y \to 0} f(0,y)= \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{-y}{y} = -1,$$ while $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x,0)= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x} = 1.$$

Comment: Thank you. Is there any problem with the $(x,y)\to(x,x)$ notation? (which then substituting into the limit gives $\infty$, hence it does not exist)

Comment: Of course, I am saying $y \to x$ just as you would with $y \to a$ (i.e. it tends to but not reaches that value).

Comment: @Dzoooks while this shows it is not continuous at $(0,0)$, how to do it in general for any $(x,y)$ such that $x=y$?

Answer (score 0):

Take polar coordinates:

$$x=r\cos{t}$$ $$y=rsin{t}$$ where $r>0$ and $t\in [0,2\pi]\setminus \{\pi/4\}$

So after plugging in the above you will have that $$\lim_{r\to 0}f(r,t)=\frac{\cos{t}+\sin{t}}{\cos{t}-\sin{t}}$$

For $t=0$ the result is $1$ and for $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is $-1$

So the limit does not exist,since it depends on $t$.